# Shake UI GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I go about shaking UI GameObject in Unity? As in, for it to go up and down and side to side.

I have UI Text GameObject that display points. When triggered, I want it to shake. I've tried using Vector 3 but I feel like I'm using it incorrectly. Some help or pointers would be appreciated.

Once again, it's an UI object that I want to shake on canvas.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a Tween library, like DoTween, which has a shake function: http://dotween.demigiant.com/examples.php

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a bunch of ways. Attach a script to the ui element. In the script update loop you can play with the gameObject.transform.position values. You could also use lerp to lerp back and forth to different destinations. You can do it in more ways as well but these would be the easiest to implement.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html